# Leave Non-Declared Arguments to Their Default Values

Tags: python, flask, put, flask-restful

I am creating a RESTful API using Flask and Flask-Restful and am running into a problem with PUT requests and the arguments. I have a JSON file that contains:

```
{
    "checked": 1465628401,
    "number": 21600,
}
```

When the user sends `"/api/v1/status?checked=10"` it changes the checked value like it should but sets *number* to null. I'm wondering if there is a way I can have it so that if a user does not specify that argument, it stays as its current value.

Right now, I define my RequestParser like:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
```

And add each argument like:

```
parser_status.add_argument('checked', type=int)
parser_status.add_argument('number', type=int)
```

So my question is, is there a way to default each JSON key to stay as its current value unless the argument is present in the PUT request?

The documentation states: *Also note: Arguments declared in your request parser but not set in the request itself will default to None.* Im wondering if there is a way to change that default.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reqparse.Argument) sais that you can add default values.

The `Argument` class and thus the `add_argument` function accepts a `default` keyword argument which itself indeed defaults to `None`.

So use it like this:

```
parser_status.add_argument("checked", type=int, default=MY_DEFAULT_VALUE)
```